# Radio Buttons Alternating PHP Form Field Function with AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, forms, twitter-bootstrap, radio-button

Have Radio Buttons to Trigger Different PHP Functions.. At the moment though, the page just flashes when the submit button is clicked!

IT SEEMS THE .PHP NEEDS TWEAKING!!

Would like the functions to perform without a page refresh, hence AJAX..

The Form field should submit a string to the PHP when the Submit Button (Return) is clicked, subject to the selected Radio button.

http://bootply.com/61461

HTML PAGE:

```
<div class="container">

  <!-- Input Section -->
  <form action="">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>A Form to input plain English and output Pig Latin</legend>
      <label></label>
      <input class="span9" type="text" id="txt1" name="yourText" placeholder="… Type Something Here …"><br><br>
      <span class="help-block">Choose whether or not you want to have the English input echoed on the output as Pig Latin:</span>
      <label class="radio inline">
      <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="english" value="english" checked>
      Echo the English Input
      </label>
      <label class="radio inline">
      <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="piglatin" value="piglatin">
      Output as Pig Latin
      </label>
      <br><br>
      <button type="submit" class="btn" onClick="showTxt(this.value)">Return</button>
    </fieldset>
  </form>

  <br><br><br>

  <!-- Output Section -->
  <span id="return-text">
    <p>Text Will Post Here</p>
  </span>

</div>
```

PHP PAGE:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Pig Latin PHP</title>
  </head>

  <body>

    <?php
    if( isset($_POST['yourText'])){
        $text = $_POST['yourText'];
    }
    function engish(){
        if( isset($_POST['optionsRadios']) &&
        $_POST['optionsRadios'] == 'english'){
            echo $text;
        }
    }
    function piglatin(){
        if( isset($_POST['optionsRadios']) &&
        $_POST['optionsRadios'] == 'piglatin'){
            echo '…pig latin php operation to be written…';
        }
    }
    echo english();
    echo piglatin();
    ?>

  </body>
</html>
```

AJAX SCRIPT (thanks to ogc-nick's answer):

```
<!-- AJAX Call to piglatin.php -->
<script>
  function showTxt(str)
  {
  var xmlhttp;
  if (str.length==0)
    { 
    document.getElementById("return-text").innerHTML="";
    return;
    }
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
  else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
      {
      document.getElementById("return-text").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
      }
    }
  xmlhttp.open("POST","piglatinajax.php", true);
  xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  var dataString = $('form').serialize();
    xmlhttp.send(dataString);
  }
```

Thanks for Looking

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your request is sending the data in the $_GET variable `q` but you php is looking for the indexes. You need to add post data in the send method like so

```
var optionsRadios = document.forms[formname].optionsRadios.value; 
var yourText = document.forms[formname].yourText.value; 
xmlhttp.send("optionsRadios=" + optionsRadios + "&yourText=" + yourText);
```

Reference: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp

Comment: Thanks, appreciate that.. What should the .php page look like?

Comment: You have the right idea, just make sure that any data you have in the javascript send method will end up in the `$_POST` array and anything you have trailing your request url after the `?` will be in the `$_GET` array. In the code you posted. The only data available to you php script would be `$_GET['q']`.

Comment: Have updated the question.. With the whole PHP page.. Thoughts?

Comment: Just make the data in your .send() method the data from your form then load it up and see if it works.

Comment: Tried this: xmlhttp.send("optionsRadios=value&yourText=value");

Comment: What's the proper .send for including the text field (name="yourText") and the radio buttons (name="optionsRadios")?

Comment: Thanks for the update! Is it working for you? Because it's still not working.. May be the .PHP ..?

Comment: I recommend using [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) or some other library to do ajax requests. It will really make your life a lot easier.